# Error:Secret API keys should not be used in your app. When use X-Platform in the headers of revenueCat Get endpoint

Tags: nestjs, request-headers, revenuecat

Revenue Cat docs clearly mentions that you can specify the operating system in the `Get` request, by specifying OS in the `headers` by using `X-Platform` property, so you can get OS specific `management_url`

```
curl --request GET \
     --url https://api.revenuecat.com/v1/subscribers/app_user_id \
     --header 'X-Platform: ios' \
     --header 'accept: application/json'
```

Refrence : https://www.revenuecat.com/reference/subscribers#the-subscriber-object

But when I use `X-Platform` in my call , it throws following error

```
{
  code: 7243,
  message: 'Secret API keys should not be used in your app.'
}
```

**My API Call In NestJs**

```
 const data = await lastValueFrom<SubscriberInfo>(
      this.httpService
        .get(`${revenueCatBaseURl}${userId}`, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Platform': 'ios',
            accept: 'application/json',
            Authorization: 'Bearer token,
          },
        })
        .pipe(
          map((res) => {
            return res.data;
          }),
          catchError((error: AxiosError) => {
            console.log(error.response.data);
            throw 'An error happened!';
          }),
        ),
    );
```

**The call works fine without `X-Platform`**